# Javascript to detect when a new iFrame is created by other Javascript code, and then interact with the iFrame contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on our organisation's new web-based CMS, so a website that we have only limited control over. I am trying to create some in-page Javascript/jQuery to help us to customise things more than out-of-the-box customisations it provides. (e.g. hide divs, add extra buttons, create calculated values to add to form input boxes etc.)

Many of the "edit record" buttons in this CMS (iMIS 200, fact fans) use its baked-in, core Javascript to *create* a new iFrame in the page, and it display it to edit the record, then you push "Save" and the iFrame closes.

I am pretty new to Javascript/jQuery, just had a bash at various simple things over the years. But I'm wondering if it's possible to:

- detect that a new iFrame has been created (I know the HTML ID of it, that's fine)
- interact with that new iFrame, e.g. insert div at the top with some text

I've successfully made some (Tampermonkey) Javascript that uses parent.document to detect from an iFrame to the parent document - so I've been able to achieve some of the goals BUT these only work from Tampermonkey (i.e. that Tampermonkey script installed on that machine). I'd like to be able to use Javascript/jQuery in the pages on the parent document so that the tweaks I'm making are universal, not machine-based.

Hopefully I've made it clear what I mean...

Thanks in advance for any advice/hints/tip you can offer!

Chris

**EDIT:** I have realised I *don't* have an ID for the iFrame actually, but can use an div with an ID inside the iFrame that gets created instead..

Also, I have to refer to jQuery as jQuery(... not $(... for some reason in the Javascript.

Comment: Users posting questions are supposed to make a proper research and an effort of their own, which you obviously haven't, providing a [_sample within the question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do and come back with it, if you can't make it work. If anything is unclear, please reread [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can identify an element inside which the iframe is going to be created. You can use [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to achieve that:

```
//select element inside which an iframe will be created
//changes made inside that element will be tracked by the observer
var target = $( ".outer-iframe" )[0]; 

var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
  mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
    var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // get the list of added nodes
    if( newNodes !== null ) { // if any node was added
        var $nodes = $( newNodes ); // create a jQuery set
        $nodes.each(function() { // for each node
            var $node = $( this );
            if( $node.is("iframe#id-that-you-expect") ) { 
                //if that's the iframe you are looking for
                //add a div at the begining of it's body
                $node.find("body").prepend("<div>Your div inside iframe</div>") 
            }
        });
    }
  });    
});

// observer configuration
var observerConfig = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

// start observing
observer.observe(target, observerConfig);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I have tried it and in doing so realised a few things: a) I have to reference jQuery as jQuery(... not $(... [Don't really understand enough about that to know why]. 
b) I've discovered the iFrame doesn't have an ID like I thought, but there is an ID for a container inside the iFrame that I could use.
c) I'm assuming all this code can go in the <script> function that I'm using for other jQuery: function pageLoad() {....}

Comment: @ChrisLydon a) $ is not working due to it either being overwritten or jQuery.noConflick() being used. It's usually the case in CRM/ERP web apps (and also in WordPress). If you want to stick to using $ instead of jQuery, you can wrap your code in an IIFE like this `(function ($) {  /* your code */ })(jQuery);` c) yes, it can be put in a `<script>` tag, inside `$( document ).ready(function() {/* code here */})` most preferably

Comment: I can't get this work.... In your graciously provided code, I am changing all the `$(` to `jQuery(` because that's how this system seems to want it. The outer frame for the page is the Body tag `id=MainBody`. I don't have an id for the newly created iFrame (which is generated when I push a button on the page), but surely jQuery should find it with just `"iframe"` not `"iframe#id"`, as its the only iFrame? Nothing gets prepended to this iFrame. Fundamentally, I don't know if my changes to your code to use `jQuery(` not `$(` are correct. (I left the $nodes and $node as they are.)